# SQL Query takes less than 1 sec in SSMS and forever in code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running this query against a quite big table (i guess, around 150-200 000 rows):

```
select count(Distinct(eti.Email)) FROM table1 eti 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ti on ti.Email = eti.Email and ti.SiteId = eti.Site_Id 
WHERE eti.Site_Id=1
```

In SMMS (SQL Server Management Studio) it takes less than 1 secound to execute but when I try to execute from my ASP.NET-site it times out.

I'm using PetaPoco to fetch the data which "under the hood" executes this code:

```
using (var cmd = CreateCommand(_sharedConnection, sql, args))
{
    object val = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    OnExecutedCommand(cmd);
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T));
}
```

I've been reading about that SSMS has som "special settings" when it executes the query? I really need to get this up and running.

Could the "MARS"-setting in the connection be have any impact on this? How do i debug and find the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: In my experience, when something like this happens, what SQL Server executes isn't what you think it executes. Can you check with the profiler what the command that actually is? It may be wrapped in sp_executesql, for example.

Comment: Is the query parameterised when called from your app? You may be experiencing parameter sniffing. In any case you should compare the two execution plans. SSMS does not have any "special settings". The default setting for `ARITHABORT` is different but that just means the cached plans won't be shared. See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Indeed it adds "sp_executesql", the query looks like this: exec sp_executesql N'select count(Distinct(eti.Email)) FROM table1 eti LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ti on ti.Email = eti.Email and ti.SiteId = eti.Site_Id where eti.Site_Id=@0 ',N'@0 int',@0=1 is sp_executesql a bad ting?

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help!

I have finally found the issue (and it's a little embarrassing)... I found this blog question from msdn forums about sp_executesql being slow: 
and Dan Guzman who is SQL Server MVP answers: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/3cb08860-49a0-432a-8605-0af6b374dded/

> Another possible issue is data type mismatches between the parameters and the column data types, resulting in non-sargable expressions and a bad plan.  Please post your query and table DDL if you need further help.

So i doubled checked and it turned out that table2 had both the Email and the SiteId-fields set as "Nullable", changing them to match table1 fixed the issue.

Comment: Probably that wasn't actually the issue. Joining on columns of the same datatype but with one side nullable and the other not doesn't cause an implicit cast. Also that wouldn't explain why the same query ran fine from SSMS. Altering the table will have caused the bad execution plan to be dropped from the cache. You should have captured the execution plans as now they will be gone hampering investigation of the true cause. Though you could try and reproduce by generating a plan for a highly selective `Site_Id` and seeing how that fares when passed a very common `Site_Id`

Comment: I executed these two querys in SSMS: 
go
select count(Distinct(eti.Email)) FROM table1 eti LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ti on ti.Email = eti.Email and ti.SiteId = eti.Site_Id where eti.Site_Id=1

go
exec sp_executesql N'select count(Distinct(eti.Email)) FROM table1 eti LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ti on ti.Email = eti.Email and ti.SiteId = eti.Site_Id where eti.Site_Id=@0 ',N'@0 int',@0=1

Comment: And the last one took forever (in SSMS as well). I just chnaged the nullable types and ran the query again and it was fast.

I was wrong i the question when saying that it was the same SQL statement since PetaPoco wraps the query with "sp_executesql".